# What are the risks associated with manually creating Primary Keys?

Tags: jpa, glassfish, eclipselink

In my Java EE application that runs on GlassFish 4.1 with Derby 10.11.1.1, I am currently using the following technique to auto generate my primary keys in each of my jpa Entities:

```
@TableGenerator(name = "Entity1_Generator", table = "ID_Gen", pkColumnName = "GEN_NAME", valueColumnName = "GEN_VAL", initialValue = 0, allocationSize = 1)
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "Entity1_Generator")
private Long id;
```

I decided yesterday that it would be nice to move the `@Id` to a `@MappedSuperclass` and then Extend the mapped superclass in each of my entities.  Unfortunately, I discovered quickly that EclipseLink does not support overriding the `@TableGenerator` or `@SequenceGenerator` on subclasses.  The following are a few references:

- [MappedSuperclass - Change SequenceGenerator in Subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8589928/mappedsuperclass-change-sequencegenerator-in-subclass)
- [Why does eclipselink 2.5.0 does not support Override TableGenerator or SequenceGenerator in subclasses while hiberate does support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18943310/why-does-eclipselink-2-5-0-does-not-support-override-tablegenerator-or-sequenceg)

Based on this information, I came up with the following options:

- Abandon my goal of moving the `@Id` to my mapped superclass. (Boo!)
- Use a single `@TableGenerator` for all my entities. (Yuk!)
- Create a custom generator by extending the EclipseLink Sequence object.
- Abandon `@GeneratedValue` and create the primary keys using an EJB.

I review the following EclipseLink Custom Sequencing information but wasn't sure from the documentation that I would be able to grab distinguishing information that would allow me to create a sequence for each entity.

- https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/CustomSequencing

I am now thinking that it would be easy to create an stateless or singleton EJB that would control my sequences.  I would simply remove the `@GeneratedValue` annotation from my code and perform the following code before persisting my entity.

```
myEntity.setId(idGenerator.getNextMyEntityId());
```

Using the IDGenerator to control my primary key generation, would have the following advantages:

- Move `@Id` to mapped superclass.
- Remove `@TableGenerator` from each entity.
- Complete control over how sequences are generated.

What are the risks associated with using an EJB to create my Primary Keys?

Comment: I'm no expert, but at least you'd have to figure out how far the sequences have gotten after a server restart. Also aren't you just moving a couple of lines of code pr. entity to the EJB instead? In case of a persistenceexception the id would now be set, but I don't know if that could be a problem

Comment: Instead of using custom sequencing, you can set the sequence at the mapped superclass level and then override it in a descriptor customizer for any subclasses: http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/a_customizer.htm  With this you should be able to add any sequence to the subdescriptors.  I don't have a code example handy though that shows adding a standard sequence object to a descriptor though - you may have to check for older native TopLink/EclipseLink project examples.

Comment: I compared creating entities using my IDGenerator singleton EJB versus using @TableGenerator and determined that I can create entities in about half the time with my IDGenerator. I also found a quick way to determine the last ID created if the server should crash before the IDGenerator writes the NEXT_ID to the database. Even though I am only saving myself a few lines of code in each entity, I will continue moving forward with IDGenerator since it is faster and it gives me more control over the ID creation process.

Comment: Control over the ID process is great if you need it, but with sequence preallocation, I'm not sure how your implementation can be any faster then a table sequence.